# What does grep do when it's not running the CPU?

Tags: grep, performance

When looking for matches with `grep`, I often notice that the subsequent search takes significantly less time than the first-- e.g. 25s vs. 2s.  Obviously, it's not by reusing the data structures from its last run-- those should've been deallocated.  Running a `time` command on `grep`, I noticed an interesting phenomenon:

```
real    24m36.561s
user    1m20.080s
sys     0m7.230s
```

Where does the rest of the time go?  Is there anything I can do to make it run fast every time? (e.g. having another process read the files, before `grep` searches them.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It  is quite often related to the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

The first time, the data has to be read (physically) from the disk.

The second time (for not too big files) it is likely to be sitting in the page cache.

So you could issue first a command like [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) to bring the (not too big) file into the page cache (i.e. in RAM), then a second [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) (or any program reading the file) would generally run faster.

<sup>(however, the data still needs to be read from the disk at some time)</sup>

See also (sometimes useful in your application programs, but practically rarely) [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) & [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) and perhaps [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) & [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) & [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) etc....

Read also [LinuxAteMyRAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

BTW, this is why it is recommended, when benchmarking a program, to run it several times. Also, this is why it could be useful to buy more RAM (even if you don't run programs using all of it for their data).

If you want to understand more, read some book like e.g. [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Yep, I tested it, and `cat` does do the trick.

Comment: So, the `TL;DR` answer is "[block waiting for] I/O".

Comment: *Useful* use of cat

Comment: @PaulDraper Not really :) `cat` + `grep` is still going to take longer than `grep` alone.

Comment: @chepner Unless you can multithread and use `cat` as a cheap pre-fetch while you're doing something else, in prep for the `grep` of interest.

Comment: @chepner Not if cat is run pre-emptively (i.e., before you know for sure, which term `grep` will search for, if any.) – Alex 7 mins ago

Comment: Sure, if you can run it as a background process while you are doing other stuff to get ready for the first call to `grep`. Otherwise, you are just *delaying* the first call to `grep`. (Or, as I just noticed, exactly what @hBy2Py said; I really shouldn't read comments in reverse order.)

Comment: @PaulDraper
`cat < input-file | cat | grep 'expr' | cat | cat > output-file` (:trolling:)..........

Comment: @MarkKCowan: [Lovely cats!](http://montypython.net/scripts/spam.php)   :-)   ⁠

Comment: @G-Man: You can also replace two of the `cat`s with `tac` for the same effect and higher RAM usage :D  Or all of the cats with tac

Answer (score -1):

In a network storage environment, there can also be relatively significant delays when you first access a file that resides on a "filer" separate from the server. Once that file has been accessed on the server, it will be cached locally and subsequent access to the data will be much faster.

Here's an experiment just computing a checksum of the file data -- not grep. The first invocation is slow, and subsequent ones are fast.

```sh
> du -Dh file_348m
348M    file_348m

> /usr/bin/time md5sum file_348m
738709b181b52ddfcef3413997f91462  file_348m
0.60user 0.15system 0:03.02elapsed 25%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1524maxresident)k
708144inputs+0outputs (0major+80minor)pagefaults 0swaps

> /usr/bin/time md5sum file_348m
738709b181b52ddfcef3413997f91462  file_348m
0.67user 0.06system 0:00.73elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1524maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+80minor)pagefaults 0swaps

> /usr/bin/time md5sum file_348m
738709b181b52ddfcef3413997f91462  file_348m
0.65user 0.07system 0:00.73elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1524maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+80minor)pagefaults 0swaps

> /usr/bin/time md5sum file_348m
738709b181b52ddfcef3413997f91462  file_348m
0.66user 0.06system 0:00.73elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1524maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+80minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: I'd appreciate comments for downvote(s), as I don't know how to interpret them. I believe my answer description is correct. Perhaps the command example isn't clear? Or you don't like that I didn't benchmark the grep command? (I intentionally used a simpler command, md5sum, to try to illustrate my point.)

Comment: I think the reason is, your post did not add any new information relevant to what I was asking.  I already knew there was a delay, and the first answer already gave an explanation of why it's happening.  But yeah, I get downvotes without explanation too.  Even on questions with good answers.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for suggesting a reason. I was trying to distinguish between the overhead time to move data from local storage to memory, which the first answer described, and the overhead time to move data from network storage to the local server. I will think if I could describe this more clearly or provide better command examples.

Comment: I guess after reading your post, my thought is, it is still the overhead of moving data from wherever it's stored, to memory.  Whether it's from network storage, or from local storage, doesn't matter-- Unix still sees it as moving from a directory to memory. p.s.-- it looks like my explanation is correct-- my comment with the reason got an upvote.

Comment: I see, I was adding a distinction that isn't important to what you were looking for. OK. By the way, I upvoted your comment, so it doesn't solve the question of the downvoting reason. :-)

Comment: Oh, whops.  So I guess we'll wait to see whether someone else cares enough to give another evaluation of your post.